# Error messages displayed without correct classes in YII2?

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, yii2

I have just started learning YII and have trouble displaying my error messages correctly in a form. I am using the following code:

> ```
>  $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
>     <?= $form->field($model, 'name'); ?>
>     <?= $form->field($model, 'email'); ?>
>
>     <div class="form-group">
>         <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']); ?>
>     </div>
> <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
> ```

The error messages display in a black color making it harder to see. I inspected the error messages and realized that is only have a `help-block`. Can some explain what is the matter? Why the `help-block-error` class is not applied?
Thanks!

Comment: There is no `help-block-error` class, errors should be styled using `.has-error .help-block` selector. I don't this it is automagically styled by Yii itself, your theme needs to include styles for this selector.

Comment: Well, yes it is always getting harder to follow the tutorials on the net. But thanks for your response